# How to find the shortest path from vertex u to v while at least visiting one target for directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

I am struggling to perform this in O(|E|log(|V|)) worst-case time complexity where E is the list of edges and V is the vertices in the graph.

So far I tried to use an adjacency list. I first sort the graph from starting vertex u using Kahn's topology algorithm.

I then look for the next target in the sorted topology and push the minimum distance of going from vertex u to v while traversing through the target into a min-heap. I did this by using Dijkstra's algorithm to find the minimum distance from u to the target requiring minimum overall distance. I also find the minimum distance from the target to vertex v.

### Edit: Solution for directed graph

I found a solution by creating a copied graph with all the edges in reversee. I run dikjistra from source to destination then from run dikjstra again from destination to source with the graph with all reversed edges. I find overall distancing involving traversing at least one target along the way then I reuse the distance I got from the previous dikjistra executions to find the shortest path.

Comment: For a directed graph, run Dijkstra's algorithm starting at `u` to find the path length from `u` to each target. Then reverse the direction of the edges, and run Dijkstra's algorithm starting at `v` to find the path length from each target to `v`. Then, for each target, you can compute the path length that includes that target.

Answer (score 2):

let DistSrc[i] denote the shotest distance of node i from source(here u) and DistDes[i] denote the shotest distance of node i from destination.

Both DistSrc and DistDes can be found by dijkstra algorithm.

iterate over all target nodes (say ti)  and and take the minimum of (DistSrc[ti]+DistDes[ti]) over all ti.

Comment: Hi! Great answer. You could improve it by providing the time complexity analysis. Dijkstra's complexity is O(E log V). We run it twice. Then we iterate on the targets, which is proportional to T where T is the number of targets. Since T < V < E (assuming the graph is connected), then the final complexity is O(E log V + E log V + V) = O(E log V)

Comment: Also, sentence *"Both DistSrc and DistDes can be found by dijkstra algorithm."* is a bit ambiguous. Running Dijkstra once gives the distance of every node from one given source node. To find the distance from u to every node, and from every node to v, Dijkstra's algorithm needs to be run twice, once from u, once to v. Also note that the graph is directed, so although Dijkstra can find the distance from every node to v, that requires looking at the edges "from the other direction".